# Get git commit SHA for use in command line utility

Tags: bash, git, shell, command-line, command-substitution

I want to run this command:

```
$ ionic-cloud build web --app-id=<APPFLOW APP ID> --commit=<GIT COMMIT SHA>
```

In order to do this I need to know my Git commit SHA. I know I can get this with:

```
git show -s --format=%H
```

Now how do I combine these things together to use in the command line? Should I make a shell script to do this?

Comment: Add an **example** output of this command to your question: `git show -s --format=%H`

Comment: Use `git rev-parse` rather than `git show`: it's simpler and produces the hash ID by default, so `git rev-parse HEAD` gets you the current commit's hash ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  you want to include the output of the first command use:

```
ionic-cloud build web --app-id=<APPFLOW APP ID> --commit="$(git show -s --format=%H)"
```